# Random wave texture width, but with a normalized amplitude

Tags: procedural, mathematics, shader-nodes

I've been trying to make a procedural triangle or saw wave texture, where every gradient segment has a random width, but each starts at a value of 0 and linearly raises to 1 (and in the case of a triangle, goes back to 0), but I can't figure it out, is it even possible? Saw wave is probably better as that can be easily converted to a triangle wave using pingpong math node.

The closest I've been able to get is to use a single axis voronoi texture with random set to max, but that also randomizes the peaks. If only there was a way I could create single value columns for each wave that has a value of its respective peak, then I could easily normalize them.

Here are two different views of the same thing, top and side. What I want to achieve is that each of the spikes in the right view reaches the top of the plane.

[image]